# C# Access a form's comboBox items from another form

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I have two forms: form1 and form 2. The comboBox is in form2. I am trying to add an item to the list of the comboBox choices from form1. Here is what I've tried so far.

```
form1:          
var form2 = new Form2();                   
if (variable == "value") {           
  form2.Controls["ComboBox1"].Items.Add("another item")          
}

this.Hide();          
form2.Show;
```

The problem with this one is that it doesn't let me select the items. (It doesn't let me type in .Items.Add)

---

Ive also tried to make the comboBox public by clicking on it in the form and changing the private to  public. This is what it looks like when I change it.

```
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
}
```

but when I try to access `comboBox1` all I get as available is:

```
comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

form2.comboBox1    //This doesn't work            
form2.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged   //This is the only option available
```

I probably made a ton of mistakes but that's because im new to this. I just started learning so if you could please try to explain simply that would help. Please avoid the get{} set{} things if possible. And please explain to me how to make the buttons and other things in a different form public because I know clicking on it and changing the private to public isn't the right way like I did in the example above.

Comment: Is this homework? I swear I saw this exact same question, asked in VB.Net two days ago... I can even remember I was going to answer suggesting to use the same SelectedIndexChanged event for both comboboxes.  Its practically the same as @TuTran's answer except on both Form Constructors you would assign the single EventHandler for both ComboBoxes SelectedIndexChange events...

Answer (score 6):

go to visual UI designer and find modifiers in properties and change it to Public:
[image]

now you need a small change in code:

```
var form2 = new Form2();                   
if (variable == "value") {           
 form2.ComboBox1.Items.Add("another item");      
}

this.Hide();          
form2.Show;
```

Comment: Worked Perfect for me. At least you get a +1 from me ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, half an hour not getting why can't access the text and it was as simple as make it available through "public" :)

Answer (score 1):

You should write a public method on the Form2 adding items to the combo box on this.

```
public class Form2 : Form {
    ...

    public void AddItem(object item) {
       comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    ...
}
```

That way, you just call that method on Form1.

```
form2.AddItem(variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's best to use event handler to do this, you register an event handler in form 1 with the corresponding method when this event handler is called. Then call this event handler in form2. The method will be responsible to add item to the combo box.

Comment: Check my comment, I think we were thinking the same thing, maybe you could elaborate your answer with some sample code that demonstrates the solution?

Comment: Can you give an example please